# Can you Counterspell a spell cast using a Ring of Spell Storing?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, spellcasting, counterspelling

**Is a spell cast using a *[Ring of Spell Storing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing)* observable, in the sense that you could *[Counterspell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell)* it?** Or is it essentially same as if you cast a spell using something like a Sorcerer's Subtle Spell metamagic, or some other means of hiding or not needing the components of the spell? Does it maybe even depend on the type of spell, ie. if the spell *effect* is observable, it could be counterspelled, but not if there is no visible effect?

Relevant snippet from the ring description:

> While wearing this ring, you can cast any spell stored in it. The spell uses the slot level, spell save DC, spell attack bonus, and spellcasting ability of the original caster, but is otherwise treated as if you cast the spell.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised I did not find a duplicate... Maybe someone finds one.

Answer (score 0):

### It can be Counterspelled

You provide all the information necessary

> While wearing this ring, you can **cast any spell** stored in it. [...] treated as if **you cast the spell**.

The action you are taking is to 'Cast a spell'. The means of casting it, and the fact that you're potentially using another spellcasters' statistics, are not material to the fact that you are casting a spell. Counterspell's text is 'broad' in that it doesn't specify any 'specific way' (ie 'normally' or 'using a spell slot') for it to take effect.

> You attempt to interrupt a creature in the process of **Casting a Spell**. If the creature **is cas⁠ting a sp⁠ell** of 3rd Level or lower, its spell fails and has no Effect. If it is cas⁠ting a sp⁠ell of 4th Level or higher ...

Comment: I'd like this answer to also explain, how does a character *know* they can cast a Counterspell in this case. I believe general ruling is, that Subtle Spell metamagic prevents counterspelling by this same mechanic.

Comment: The Ring of Spell storing does not specify that you cast the stored spell without somatic or verbal components, so presumably you still need the same gestures and magical words the spell might require. This identifier allows another spellcaster to Counterspell your spell.

Comment: The general rules for magic item spellcasting do specify that you cast without components: "Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item, often by expending charges from it. The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell and caster level, doesn’t expend any of the user’s spell slots, and requires no components unless the item’s description says otherwise."

Comment: @JohnW.b User of the ring doesn't need to be spellcaster or know anything about magic, so performing spell components doesn't seem to be required.

Comment: I would argue that the Ring of Spell Storing is different than other "Cast from an item" spells, but I see that it could also be argued that it's the same with specific exceptions (using the caster's statistics instead of the lowest level). [This is the Q/A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/152178/28326) regarding the inability to Counter spells without components, so if that's the case, then I'd agree a different answer can be made